# Как можно ускорить код поиска в List C#

Tags: c#, оптимизация

Есть класс. В ней для переопределил метод `ToString()` который создает строку в формате ФИО (и заодно удаляет пробелы лишние, если такоевые есть).

```
public struct FullName
{
    public string Name;
    public string Surname;
    public string Patronymic;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        var str = string.Join(' ', Surname?.Trim(), Name?.Trim(), Patronymic?.Trim()).Trim();
        return str;
    }
}
```

И есть класс с методом `Search`. В этом классе есть поле `List<FullName>`.

```
private readonly List<FullName> _fullNames; //заполняются извне

public List<string> Search(string prefix)
{
    var items = _fullNames.ToArray();
    List<string> result = new List<string>();

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(prefix) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(prefix))
        throw new ArgumentNullException();

    if (prefix.Length > 100)
        throw new ArgumentException();


    for(int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
    {
        if (items[i].ToString().Contains(prefix))
            result.Add(items[i].ToString());
    }
    return result;
}
```

Вот сама задача (.NET 3.1):
Надо сделать поиск физ. лиц. Дана структура `FullName` с полями `Surname`, `Name`, `Patronomyc` и метод `Search(string prefix)` в отдельном классе.

Условия:

1. Поиск только по префиксу, без исправления ошибок и без поиска по подстроке.
2. Поиск по префиксу должен работать только по полной строке сформированной из FullName (нет случаев когда в FullName есть имя и фамилия и надо искать одновременно по префиксу имени и фамилии)
3. Строка из FullName имеет вид: "Фамилия Имя Отчество", один или несколько свойств могут быть `null`.
4. Результат выполнения метода может быть отсортирован в каком угодно порядке.

Comment: Какие правила у поиска? Если есть запись "Иванов Иван Иванович", и префикс "Иван Иванов", запись должна найтись? Или префикс строго должен соответствовать порядку слов в полном имени?

Comment: @AndreiKhotko если префикс "Ива", то найдутся все, у кого фамилия/имя/отчество начинаются на этот префикс. Так же, должно и работать если префикс будет равен полному ФИО (т.е если введено Иванов Иван Иванович, то и найдется этот(или несколько) человек). К слову, есть немного оптимизации. Сейчас время выполнения 74579 вместо 500000

Comment: Тогда еще вопрос: а вам нужно всех пользователей выводить сразу? Просто если задача - это автозаполнение для пользователя, либо выбор нужной записи для ее дальнейшего редактирования, то можно выводить первых N совпадений. Это тоже ускорит поиск. А так, из списка вы больше не сможете выжать производительности. Если нужно ускорение - стоит смотреть в сторону поисковых движков, либо реализации поиска в БД, а не в C#. Либо попробовать самому написать поисковый движок, если позволяют время и ресурсы

Comment: @AndreiKhotko нет, пользователей выводить никуда не нужно

Comment: Тогда используйте в `return` перед `ToList()` - [Take(N)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.take?view=net-6.0). Если нужен значительный прирост в производительности поиска - рекомендую рассмотреть, например, этот движок с открытым исходным кодом: https://lucenenet.apache.org/

Comment: @AndreiKhotko с использованием `Take(N)` код стал быстрее (на 10000 наносекунд), но этого всё еще недостаточно (сейчас 66539 вместо 74579). Я не особо понимаю, что за движки.. если что, nuget пакеты нельзя устанавливать.

Comment: @Aarnihauta проверки на null и Trim() должны выполняться при задании свойств, как у вас было в начальной версии. В методе ToString() и при сравнении строк в поиске эти проверки не нужны. Также зачем нужно преобразование List в Array в начале метода Search? И попробуйте распараллелить обработку по комментарию к моему ответу ниже.

Comment: `var items = _fullNames.ToArray();` - выкинуть это.

Comment: Зачем вы изменили код в вопросе? Мне теперь ответ переписывать чтоли полностью надо? Хотел дописать анализ кода, но выкинул недописанным из ответа.

Comment: @aepot я изменил на наиболее быстрый вариант на текущий момент до которого сам дошел. К слову, узнал, 1000 наносекунд это предел.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У вас задача поиска по префиксу - для этого есть специальная структура данных - префиксное дерево или trie

Код поиска простой. Добавим пару методов в вашу структуру (чтобы избавиться от дубликатов в конце)

```
public struct FullName
{
    public string Name;
    public string Surname;
    public string Patronymic;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        var str = string.Join(" ", Surname?.Trim(), Name?.Trim(), Patronymic?.Trim()).Trim();
        return str;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return obj is FullName name
        && Name == name.Name
        && Surname == name.Surname
        && Patronymic == name.Patronymic;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int hash = 17;
        if (Name != null)
            hash = hash * 23 + Name.GetHashCode();
        if (Surname != null)
            hash = hash * 23 + Surname.GetHashCode();
        if (Patronymic != null)
            hash = hash * 23 + Patronymic.GetHashCode();
        return hash;
    }
}
```

Потом определим узел дерева с нужными методами

```
public class TrieNode
{
    private FullName? data;
    private Dictionary<char, TrieNode> children = new Dictionary<char, TrieNode>();

    public void Add(string path, FullName data)
    {
        if (path == null) return;
        Add(path, 0, data);
    }

    private void Add(string path, int index, FullName data)
    {
        if (index == path.Length)
        {
            this.data = data;
            return;
        }

        var c = path[index];
        if (!children.ContainsKey(c)) children.Add(c, new TrieNode());
        children[c].Add(path, index + 1, data);
    }

    public void GetByPrefix(string prefix, HashSet<FullName> result)
    {
        GetByPrefix(prefix, 0, result);
    }

    private void GetByPrefix(string prefix, int index, HashSet<FullName> result)
    {
        if (data.HasValue)
            result.Add(data.Value);

        if (index >= prefix.Length)
        {
            foreach (var node in children.Values)
                node.GetByPrefix(prefix, index, result);
        }
        else
        {
            var c = prefix[index];
            if (children.ContainsKey(c))
                children[c].GetByPrefix(prefix, index + 1, result);
        }
    }
}
```

Ну и использование элементарное

```
TrieNode root = new TrieNode();

var names = new FullName[] { 
    new FullName() {Surname = "Ivanov", Name = "Ivan", Patronymic = "Petrovich"},
    new FullName() {Surname = "Vasilyev", Name = "Ivan", Patronymic = "Petrovich"},
};  

foreach(var name in names) {
    root.Add(name.ToString(), name);
    root.Add(name.Name, name);
    root.Add(name.Surname, name);
    root.Add(name.Patronymic, name);
}

var ret = new HashSet<FullName>();
root.GetByPrefix("Iva", ret);
root.GetByPrefix("Pet", ret);   
foreach(var name in ret) Console.WriteLine(name.ToString());
```

Вывод в консоль

```
Vasilyev Ivan Petrovich
Ivanov Ivan Petrovich
```

Answer (score 1):

Предложения по оптимизации:

1. Устранить дублирование алгоритма поиска: сначала выполняется перебор _fullNames и запись результатов в searched, потом опять выборка из _fullNames через LINQ.
2. Использовать для поиска подстроки метод [Contains](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=net-6.0).

Цитата из [Практическое руководство. Поиск по строкам](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/how-to/search-strings):

> Регулярные выражения больше подходят для поиска или проверки
> соответствия шаблону, а не для поиска отдельной строки текста.

Сравнение производительности [Performance Test — String.Contains vs String.IndexOf vs Regex.IsMatch](https://medium.com/theburningmonk-com/performance-test-string-contains-vs-string-indexof-vs-regex-ismatch-724aa0133bd)

3. Вызов .Trim() в GetPersonalDataAsString не нужен. Кстати, метод GetPersonalDataAsString можно изменить на переопределение метода .[ToString()](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=net-6.0)

Для всех изменений желательно замерять время выполнения, например, через [Stopwatch](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=net-6.0).

Для дальнейших оптимизаций необходимы дополнительные данные по задаче, например, какое ориентировочно количество ФИО в списке _fullNames и что может приходить в prefix. Например, если в prefix может приходить что-то вида "Иван Иванов", то алгоритм не сработает.

Еще, если нужно возвращать только ФИО и поиск только по ним, тогда может быть лучше работать сразу со строками, а не со структурой. Тогда не понадобится множество раз вызывать метод string.Join.

Также нужно ограничение на длину префикса, например, минимум 3 символа.

Comment: Можно еще поэкспериментировать с распараллеливанием, как указано в примере [How to: Write a simple Parallel.ForEach loop](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-a-simple-parallel-foreach-loop) для метода GetPrimeListWithParallel.

Comment: Если уже цель сделать быстрее - необходимо НЕ использовать LINQ т.к. он достаточно медленный. Удобство использования приносит в жертву быстродействие.

Answer (score 0):

А вы уверены,  сортировка деревом быстрая?  У меня скопированный код от пользователя "tym32167" ,  увеличился по результатам на 21лям наносекунд, по сравнению с вариантом из LINQ , который был всего 9к.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).